# How do unmanaged export codes get compiled (Using C# dll in Metatrader)?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unmanaged, mql4

I have been recently working on developing a simple C# library to use in mql4 (the scripting language used in Metatrader). So I had to use NuGet's DllExport for .Net. Everything working relatively nice. But I am curious about this question:
Does Metatrader bear the compiling load of the exported dll or .Net's CLR is still responsible for the exported C# methods?
If the former is the case which I suspect it is, how can I have the dll run separately over .Net, while waiting for data transmission request from my mql script in Metatrader?
What I'm looking for is to be able to lift the compiling load from the least optimized compiler, not worrying about the size and complexity of my code.

Comment: You are micro-optimizing without having any idea whatsoever if this is actually necessary and no idea how to actually implement it.  Not a good place to be.  Luckily it is very simple to do, just run Ngen.exe on your assemblies so they are compiled ahead-of-time.  It is certainly no slamdunk that it will be faster, you must test both a cold start and a warm start of the program.  That requires you to *measure*, the thing you did not do yet.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, since it's not a serious project, I dare diving deep inside what I barely understand for the sake of learning. Thanks for the suggestion. But I think you cannot say it's micro-optimizing in general, no matter the compilers. Certain compilers are vastly known for their poor performance; Like in Creation Kit's Papyrus, a few dozen lines of script could become problematic and result in a huge FPS drop.

Comment: Isn't a .DLL compiled binaries? They don't need to be compiled again on each run no?

Comment: @ Joseph Lee : That is exactly where I am confused. As far as I know, C# compiler turns my code into an assembly which is my dll file, and then that assembly turns into native code during runtime. My question is, when I create a dll file from my code which implements unmanaged dll export, and use the code in another code like in metatrader, who carries the burden of the JIT compiler of .net?